# Equivalent ruby code for PHP MD5 Key

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I tried the equivalent ruby code for the following PHP code.

PHP code:

```
 var  $secretKey = "19535CF3D949D4EF56F8D3D4ED78C505";
 $sign=md5 ($post_data.$this->secretKey );
```

Tried Ruby code:

```
secretKey = "19535CF3D949D4EF56F8D3D4ED78C505"
Digest::MD5.hexdigest(post_data, secretkey)
```

This throws ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) error. Can anybody help me with the correct equivalent ruby code.

Comment: `Digest::MD5.hexdigest(post_data + secretkey)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to concatenate your `post_data` and `secretkey` values in the same way that you're doing using the `.` operator in PHP, so that you're only passing a single string to the MD5 digest function.

```
Digest::MD5.hexdigest(post_data + secretkey)
```

is the simplest method, though you could also use

```
Digest::MD5.hexdigest(post_data << secretkey)
```

or

```
Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{post_data}#{secretkey}")
```